# Ruby: Hash w/ Arrays, Returning Associated Key If Value Is In Array

Tags: ruby, hash

New to Ruby and have run out of ideas.  I have an array of books that I would like to 1) Shelve 2) Find which shelf it is on 3) Remove it from the associated shelf if found.  For brevity I have an array of 6 books.  Each shelf contains 5 books.

```
library_catalog = [ "Book1", "Book2", "Book3", "Book4", "Book5", "Book6" ]
shelves = Hash.new(0)
catalog_slice = library_catalog.each_slice(5).to_a
count = 1

catalog_slice.each do | x |
shelves.merge!(count=>x)
count+=1
end
```

From this I know have a Hash w/ arrays as such

```
{1=>["Book1", "Book2", "Book3", "Book4", "Book5"], 2=>["Book6"]}
```

This is where I'm having trouble traversing the hash to find a match inside the array and return the key(shelf).  If I have title = "Book1" and I am trying to match and return 1, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
shelves.select { |k,v| v.include?("Book1")}.keys.first
```

selected the hashes that have a value equal to the title you are looking for (in this case "Book1")
get the keys for these hashes as an array
get the first entry in the array.

to remove the Book from the shelf try this:

```
key = shelves.select { |k,v| v.include?("Book1")}.keys.first
shelves[key].reject! { |b| b == "Book1" }
```

get a reference to the array and then reject the entry you want to remove

Comment: I had tried this approach but didn't know about .keys.first which returned the data I required.  Quick follow up. Now that I have the key, and the Book, is there a built in method to remove Book1 from Shelf 1?

Comment: Thank you kindly. I'll add this to my toolbox and run through some trails to get it down.